# Counter Little Mac KO Punch

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Is it possible to counter Little Mac's KO Punch in SSB4? I know that it can be dodged so it seems like it should be counterable.

Comment: Just test it with a friend... I'm sure you can counter it with any counter character. Just imagine the damage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by "counter" you mean moves like Marth's down-b. In that sense, it cannot be countered.

However, there are times where you can be in kill range, get hit by the KO punch, but still not die. For example, while "egged" by Yoshi's B, you will not receive knockback when KO punched (damage still applies). This probably isn't practical as a defense though...